# What is the maximum size of a subset $A\subset \Bbb Z_n$ such that $A+A \subset \Bbb Z_n^*$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

My question, as in the title:

> What is $f(n)$ the maximum size of a subset $A\subset \Bbb Z_n$ such that $A+A \subset \Bbb Z_n^*$

where $\Bbb Z_n=\{0,1,....,n-1\}$ the ring of integers modulo $n$, $\Bbb Z_n^*$ is its group of units (i.e. multiplicative group modulo $n$) and $A+A=\{a+b, (a,b)\in A^2, a\neq b\}$

---

For example for primes $p$, we have $f(p)= \frac {p+1} 2$ , it is also straitforward to prove that :
$$f(n)\geq \frac {n} {n-\varphi(n)+1} $$

where $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function. is this the right approximation?

Edit: This can be proven recursively, by first setting $A_0=\varnothing, B_0=\varnothing$ and in each iteration, you add a new element $x$ to $A$ and all the elements $a-x, a\notin \Bbb Z_n^* $ to B. Formally

$$ A_{k+1}=A_k \cup \{x\}, B_{k+1}=B_k \cup \{a-x, a\notin \Bbb Z_n^*\}, x\notin A_k\cup B_k $$
This construction ensures that $A_k + A_k \subset \Bbb Z_n^*$. This process terminates after $m$ steps when we can't find any new element $x\notin A_m\cup B_m$, hence when $|A_{m}|+|B_{m}|=|A_{m}\cup B_{m}| \geq n$, using the fact that $ |A_{m}|(n-\varphi(n))\geq|B_{m}|$ we can deduce that $A_{m}\geq \frac {n} {n-\varphi(n)+1} $

Comment: For $p=3$, what is your set $A\subset\mathbb Z_3$ of size $|A|=2$ with $0\notin A+A$?

Comment: you're right, I made a mistake in my definition  I should add $a \neq b$ in the sumset. so that for $p=3$ I can choose $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Could you explain the "straightforward estimate"?

Comment: @W-t-P I added my proof, hopefully it's correct.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @YiFan, We will never know, but I am not surprised, even the best questions in math.StackExchange those who get hundreds of upvotes get some downvotes as well.

Comment: I wonder whether it helps to consider the addition Cayley graph induced by $Z_n\setminus Z_n^*$ on $Z_n$. This graph is almost regular, and you are asking about its independence number. Maybe, some standard estimates for the independence number can help.

Comment: @W-t-P that was very helpful I found a paper studying this exact problem.  http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-17/NNTDM-17-3-49-59.pdf